# Binary Search Tree, tree not updating after adding first node

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm implementing a binary search tree in C.

```
void add_element(node_t **head, int element) {
    if (*head == NULL) {
        node_t *new_node = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (new_node == NULL) {
            printf("Not enough memory\n");
            return;
        }
        new_node->value = element;
        new_node->left = NULL;
        new_node->right = NULL;
        *head = new_node;
    } else {
        node_t *dummy = *head;
        if (dummy->value >= element) {
            dummy = dummy->left;
            add_element(&dummy, element);
        } else {
            dummy = dummy->right;
            add_element(&dummy, element);
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the first element, the tree is not updating as when printing out only the first element appears.
The element is added when calling add_element but seems to not be updated in the original tree.

```
void log_tree(node_t *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    log_tree(head->left);
    printf("%d - ", head->value);
    log_tree(head->right);
}

void print_menu(node_t *head) {
    printf("This is a BST implementation.\n");
    
    log_tree(head);
    printf("\n");
    printf("1. Add element\n");
    printf("2. Remove element\n");
    printf("3. Search Element\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");
}

int main() {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    int run = 1;
    int choice, val;
    while (run) {
        print_menu(head);
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("\n");
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter new element: ");
                scanf("%d", &val);
                printf("\n");
                add_element(&head, val);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Enter element to be removed: ");
                scanf("%d", &val);
                printf("\n");
                remove_element(&head, val);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Enter the element you want to search: ");
                scanf("%d", &val);
                printf("\n");
                search_element(head, val);
                break;
            case 4:
                run = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the node_t:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
}

typedef struct Node node_t;
```

I'm new to C and still confused with pointers so maybe I made some mistakes in add_element.

Updated and pasted the full code.

Comment: Aside: A BST does not store duplicate values; all nodes hold unique instances of any value. If attempting to add a duplicate, the routine should simply return without doing anything to the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this ...

> ```
>         node_t *dummy = *head;
>         if (dummy->value >= element) {
>             dummy = dummy->left;
>             add_element(&dummy, element);
> ```

... the recursive `add_element` call can modify the value of local variable `dummy`, but what you *want* to enable it to modify is `(*head)->left`.  That `dummy` contains the same value as `(*head)->left` at that point, which it does, is an entirely different thing from it being the same object.

The same applies in the other branch.

I don't see any reason to involve `dummy` here.  It looks like what you want is:

```
        if ((*head)->value >= element) {
            add_element(&(*head)->left, element);
        } else {
            add_element(&(*head)->right, element);
        }
```

Comment: But how can I do head->value, head is pointer to a pointer here.

Comment: @JunkyMan, that was an error in the original version of this answer, already corrected (thanks, Vlad).  Load the new version.

Comment: Thanks it's working now, pointer is a confusing topic for me :)